# S3, Signed-URLs and Caching

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am generating signed urls on my webapp (nodejs) using the knox nodejs-library.
However the issue arises, that for every request, I need to regenerate an unique GET signed url for the current user, leaving browser's cache-control out of the game.

I've searched the web without success as browsers seem to use the full url as caching key so I am really curious how I can, under the given circumstances (nodejs, knox library) get the issue solved and use caching control while still being able to generated signed urls for each and every request as I need to verify the user's access rights.

I cannot believe there's no solution to that though.

Comment: One suggestion: leave the signing part out of the URL, and add custom http headers for authentication.

Comment: I am curious wether this is possible at all with the knox library though

Comment: have the same conundrum, Did you find a way to deal with this/

Answer (score 4):

I am working with Java AmazonS3 client, but the process should be the same.

There is a strategy that can be used to handle this situation.

You could use a fixed date time as an expiration date. I set this date to **tomorrow at 12 pm**.

Now every time you generate a url, it will be the same throughout that day until 00:00. That way browser caching can be used to some extent.

Comment: Nice way. Full explanation: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3686-calculating-a-consistent-cache-friendly-expiration-date-for-signed-urls-in-lucee-5-3-2-77.htm

Comment: I use this function `s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {Bucket: "mybucket", Key:'myImage", Expires:18000} )` which specifies the url to expire in 180000seconds or 5 hours. How to set fixed date time instead of a amount of time as expiration?

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha answer is the way. I tested his answer and it works. Read the link he provided: https://advancedweb.hu/cacheable-s3-signed-urls/. It has detailed explanation of the approach.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding @semir-deljić Answer.

Every time we call `getSignedUrl` function, it will generate new URLs. This will result in images not being cached even if `Cache Control` header is present.

Thus, we are using timekeeper library to freeze time. Now when the function is called, it thinks that the time has not passed, and it returns same URL.

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const tk = require("timekeeper");

function url4download(awsPath, awsKey) {

  function getFrozenDate() {
    return moment().startOf('week').toDate();
  }

  // Paramters for getSignedUrl function
  const params = {
    // Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html
    // Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html
    Bucket: awsBucket,
    Key: `${awsPath}/${awsKey}`,
    // 604800 == 7 days
    ResponseCacheControl: `public, max-age=604800, immutable`,
    Expires: 604800, // 7 days is max
  };

  const url = tk.withFreeze(getFrozenDate(), () => {
    return S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
  });
  return url;
}
```

**Note:**
Using `moment().toDate()`, as the timekeeper requires a Native Date Object.

Even tough the question is for using `knox` library, my answer uses aws official library.

```js
// This is how the AWS & S3 is initiliased.
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: awsAccessId,
  secretAccessKey: awsSecretKey,
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});
```

Inspiration: https://advancedweb.hu/cacheable-s3-signed-urls/

Comment: This IS THE ANSWER. The ONE key concept of how this works: trick AWS S3's `getSignedUrl` to think its in a **"preset" time** in the past. E.g. of preset time is every 10 minutes interval in the day, e.g. 1pm, 1:10pm, 1:20pm, etc. Practical example: when a user requests an image at 1:02pm, server sets to **nearest preset time** (use `timekeeper`) which is 1pm and run `s3.getSignedUrl()`; this is as if, server run `s3.getSignedUrl()` at 1pm; a request at 1.04pm will run `s3.getSignedUrl()` at 1pm and so on. Therefore, making all URLs generated from 1pm to 1:10pm the same! I tested it, it works!

Comment: I must say the phrase "freeze time" is misleading. `timekeeper`'s role here is more like a time traveller that can travel to a specified time. The code `tk.withFreeze(time, callback)` sets the Date object to specified time and then runs `callback`. So, what is useful with `timekeeper` is, you can be in any point in time, you can travel back or forward to a specified point in time and run your `callback`

Comment: This is wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

If you use CloudFront with S3, you can use a Custom Policy, if you restrict each url to the user's IP and a reasonably long timeout, it means that when they request the same content again, they will get the same URL and hence their browser can cache the content but the URL will not work for someone else (on a different IP).

(see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html)

Comment: This wouldn't work for me as users may change their IP quite frequently :(

Comment: @anderswelt did you find a solution. I am having same problem in android.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own browser cache logic by using [window.caches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

See an example in [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76805423/824979)

Answer (score 1):

When calculating signed URL you can set 'signingDate' to a fixed moment in the past e.g. yesterday morning, then calculate expiration from that moment.
Don't forget to use UTC and account for timezones.

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, GetObjectCommandInput } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";

let signingDate = new Date();
signingDate.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
signingDate.setUTCDate(signingDate.getUTCDate() - 1);

let params: GetObjectCommandInput = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: filename
};
const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client,
    command, {
        expiresIn: 3 * 3600 * 24, // 1 day until today + 1 expiration + 1 days for timezones
        signableHeaders: new Set < string > (),
        signingDate: signingDate
    });
```