# How to make browser cache identical image with different aws s3 presigned url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I generated the url similar to this for my users to retrieve image files from my aws s3 bucket:

> https://resource.my-company.com/tYERrR13341/q1/something.jpg?response-expires=Thu%2C%2008%20Nov%202018%2007%3A26%3A21%20GMT&AWSAccessKeyId=TTKIAJJBATJ89740989&Expires=1541661981&Signature=J49ebmKMdZ%2FZqwupfaD39f9e716831

Sometimes a user may refresh the page and the url to the same resource get a new set of values for `Expires` and `Signature`.

The browser will treat these two urls as different two objects, and will try to download the resource from the s3 bucket again.

It causes some performance issue. Is it possible to make a browser to be aware of the fact that, despite the difference in the parameters part of the  url, the user is trying to retrieve the same resource and hence retrieve it from its local cache?

Comment: CloudFront with signed cookies instead of presigned URLs may work better in this case https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it with caching the images presigned-url links, this will solve the problem.

When you request a pre-signed url from AWS it returns a link with expire & signature which points to the source file in your bucket, each time you make a refresh: the server will pass a request to AWS and then retrieve a new expire & signature which the browser knows nothing about, so it will fetch the same image again.

The way to tell the browser hold on do not fetch that again, is to send back the same signature when you refresh the page! It sounds easy but it can get messy so bear with me.

The solution I made was using a **"Redis"** cache layer that maps the browser loaded images to a serial.

If userA loads the page you simply check if it has been visited before by the same user and the same browser & MacAddress/IP using a "serial" you should add to the browser's local storage,

**serial structure = (browser-type&name + userID + MacAddress/IP)**, this is to make sure it works if userA login from different devices and browsers at the same time, and to make sure that you create the same serial each time userA loads the page/images from this specific browser and device.

If userA has no serial saved to local storage then add it to local the storage and go **check if the serial exists in Redis** (the user maybe logged-in before and cleared the browser-cache), if yes then remove the attached object which contains the presigned-links for your images as parameters:

```
"serial" : 
      
{ 
       
         imageID_1 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_1.jpg?.......xyz1",

         imageID_2 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_2.jpg?.......xyz2",

         imageID_3 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_3.jpg?.......xyz3"

 }
```

Then request new pre-signed url for each imageID/key that has to be loaded on the page and attach them to the "serial" object parameters in Redis. If no, then just add both "serial" + object parameters:

```
"serial" : 
      
{ 
       
         imageID_1 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_1.jpg?.......abc1",

         imageID_2 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_2.jpg?.......abc2",

         imageID_3 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_3.jpg?.......abc3"

 }
```

if the browser has a serial cached into local storage, you also have to check with each request if the imageID exists in the object parameters linked to the serial
in-order to create presigned-url for it (if it does not exist) then add it as a new parameter to the object :

```
"serial" : 
      
{ 
       
         imageID_1 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_1.jpg?.......abc1",

         imageID_2 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_2.jpg?.......abc2",

         imageID_3 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_3.jpg?.......abc3",

         imageID_4 : "https://s3.bucket.xxx/imageID_4.jpg?.......abc4",


 }
```

this is in case the user already has a serial saved into the browsers local storage, telling there is some loaded images before, so we have to check if userA is requesting the same images loaded before or he is requesting new ones.

finally you have to check if images are not loaded or forbidden to be accessed from the browser for any reason (font-end code to check and report back to the server), in this case you just remove the serial attached object and attach the new presigned-urls then send them back to the front-end (browser).

Answer (score 1):

To do this with AWS Java SDK 2, you need a custom `Signer` implementation that implements `Presigner` as well.  Here's one I created to perform the work that delegates to `AwsS3V4Signer` which performs the needed computations and is a public API.

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsS3V4Signer;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.AwsSignerExecutionAttribute;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.signer.params.Aws4PresignerParams;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionAttributes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.signer.Presigner;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.signer.Signer;
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpFullRequest;

import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

@Component
public class CustomAwsSigner implements Signer, Presigner {
    private final AwsS3V4Signer theSigner = AwsS3V4Signer.create();

    @Override
    public SdkHttpFullRequest presign(final SdkHttpFullRequest request, final ExecutionAttributes executionAttributes) {

        Instant baselineInstant = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);

        final Aws4PresignerParams signingParams = Aws4PresignerParams.builder()
            .awsCredentials(executionAttributes.getAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.AWS_CREDENTIALS))
            .signingName(executionAttributes.getAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SERVICE_SIGNING_NAME))
            .signingRegion(executionAttributes.getAttribute(AwsSignerExecutionAttribute.SIGNING_REGION))
            .signingClockOverride(Clock.fixed(baselineInstant, ZoneId.of("UTC")))
            .expirationTime(baselineInstant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
            .build();
        return theSigner.presign(request, signingParams);

    }

    @Override
    public SdkHttpFullRequest sign(final SdkHttpFullRequest request, final ExecutionAttributes executionAttributes) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("this class is only used for presigning");

    }
}
```

To get the needed components for auto wiring.

```
@Configuration
public class S3ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public S3Client amazonS3Client(final AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider, AwsRegionProvider regionProvider) {

        return S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .region(regionProvider.getRegion())
            .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider() {

        return DefaultCredentialsProvider.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public S3Presigner presigner(final AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider, AwsRegionProvider regionProvider) {

        return S3Presigner.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .region(regionProvider.getRegion())
            .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AwsRegionProvider regionProvider() {

        return DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain.builder().build();

    }


}
```

To get the expiring URL

```
@Autowired
private S3Presigner s3Presigner;

/**
 * Convert an S3 URI to a normal HTTPS URI that expires.
 *
 * @param s3Uri S3 URI (e.g. s3://mybucketname/ArchieTest/フェニックス.jpg)
 * @return https URI
 */
@SneakyThrows
public URI getExpiringUri(final URI s3Uri) {

    final GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
        GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(s3Uri.getHost())
            .key(s3Uri.getPath().substring(1))
            .overrideConfiguration(builder -> {
                builder.signer(awsSigner);
            })
            .build();

    final GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest = GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
        .signatureDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(0)) // required, but ignored
        .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
        .build();

    return s3Presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest).url().toURI();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put any `redis` cache logic or some complex logic to help cache a presign URL.

To force the browser to use the cache, we only have to make the URL the same across multiple requests. And in our case, a pre-signed URL for the same file will only vary in its signature. So we just need to make the signature identical.

And the signature is generated based on the expiry time.

So, to make the signature identical and thereby making the URLs identical, you can pass the same expiry on all the pre-signed URL generation requests for the same file requested inside a specific time window.

Let's say, if we pass the same expiry for all pre-sign calls for `file A` for a window of 10 minutes, then all those URLs will have the same signature (and so same URL) and hence will be cached.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar issue :

- [ahmad-safar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55876166/824979) works but requires and additional backend (redis)
- [hanly-nadackal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562855/824979) answer works only if your credentials are stable (which is not the case in general)

### In Short

To work in a browser, without any additional backend, you can by-pass the browser cache logic by using directly `window.caches`

### Code sample

Here is an example

```js
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import amazonS3URI from 'amazon-s3-uri';


const getSignedUrl = function({s3Uri, region, credentials}){
    const clientS3 = new S3Client({
        region,
        credentials
    });
    const {bucket, key} = amazonS3URI(s3Uri);
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({Bucket: bucket, Key: key });
    return getSignedUrl(clientS3, command);
}

const CACHE_NAME = 'custom';

const fetchWithBrowserCache = function({s3Uri, region, credentials}){
    const request = new Request(s3Uri.replace('s3://', 'https://'));
    return window.caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        return cache.match(request).then(response => {
            if(response){
                console.log(`${s3Uri} found in local cache`)
                return response;
            }
            console.log(`No response for ${request.url} found in cache`);

            return getSignedUrl({
                s3Uri: s3Uri,
                region: region,
                credentials: credentials
            }).then(url => {
                return fetch(url).then(response => {
                    console.log(`Saving ${request.url} in cache`);
                    cache.put(request, response.clone());
                    return response;
                })
            })

        })
    })
}
```

then you can use it with

```js
fetchWithBrowserCache({s3Uri: 's3://mybucket/file.png', region, credentials})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have chance to modify the server side application, you can create Authorization headers instead of creating presigned urls.

See: [5219165](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61067242/5219165)